# Opening mobile Safari's UIActivityViewController without pressing the share button

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, hyperlink, mobile-safari

I've made a web app in Ruby that sits on my iPhone's homescreen and opens full screen, [without the default Apple toolbars and menu bars](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-web-app-meta-tags/).

However, this means I'm hiding the button that opens Safari's lovely [UIActivityViewController](http://www.mactrends.info/wp-content/plugins/RSSPoster_PRO/cache/34cbb_share_ios6.jpg).

Is there a way of forcing this to open without clicking that button? i.e. Essentially building a button that performs the same function (opening the UIActionSheet) within my app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with navigator.share(), see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302475/can-i-share-a-file-with-web-share-api-on-safari/66126240#66126240

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with;

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://goo.gl"];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
    initWithActivityItems:@[url] 
    applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It is web app, there is no Objective-C/Swift code inside of it.