# Can I share a file with Web Share API on Safari

Tags: javascript, web, safari, mobile-safari, navigator

I am trying to share file with Web Share API Level 2 with the following code:

```
var file = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt", {
    type: "text/plain",
});

window.navigator.share({
    text: "Share text",
    title: "Share title",
    files: [file]
})
```

Unfortunately, file not shared with iPhone, but successfully shared on Android.

Any solution for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention that on iOS sharing works, but only `text` shared. File skipped...

Comment: Can anyone confirm that iOS 14 is allowing files yet?  Just not only text

Comment: @bbullis, tested again around 3-4 weeks ago with **iPhone XR 13.5.1 iOS** version. Still, nothing shared except basic text.

Comment: Confirmed iOS 14.4 still NOT sharing files. (tried both from Safari and Chrome. verified same website works on Android)

Comment: Thank you @OdedBenDov for updating this!

Comment: Hi. I got file sharing working now. But on Whatsapp + iOS it only works if text and title content are empty (only send the file).

Comment: Thank you @GabrielSchubert. 
Need to test it these days, iPhone 13 is already there, webshare still not :D

Answer (score 1):

I got file sharing working. But on Whatsapp + iOS it only works if text and title content empty (only send the file).

```
  let data = {};
  if (files.length > 0) {
    data.files = files;
  }
  if (title !== '')
    data.title = title;
  if (text !== '')
    data.text = text;
  if (url !== '')
    data.url = url;

  error.textContent = '';
  navigator.share(data)
    .then(() => {
  })
    .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Unsuccessful share');
    error.textContent = 'Share failed: ' + err.message;
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2q36fhb9/1/

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what I need, I have to share everything

Comment: I tested that on Iphone 13, 15.3 IOS.
File sharing worked with WhatsApp, Telegram also.
I think that gives some use cases